# Cocoa threads and class declaration connection

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, class, xcode5, void

i'm not able to find answer in any stackoverflow topic. I have faced with Threads and Class, i want to use Class controller variables and actions, in global *.m file. without attached second Class.
here is code:

**Controller.h**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Controller : NSObject
{
IBOutlet NSWindow *Main; 
IBOutlet NSButton *myButton;
}
- (void)awakeFromNib;
- (IBAction)action:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)Display(id)sender;

@end
```

**Controller.m**

```
#import "Controller.h"

@implementation Controller

- (void)awakeFromNib
{

    //At this point i can reach any variable from Controller.h

}

- (IBAction)Display:(id)sender

{

    //Same, i can reach any variable from Controller.h 

}
```

//After closing "}" and starting from new line, i can't call [Display] or anything else from Controller.h, my thread code goes here , and i want to write thread to call Display, or use awakeFromNib variables, strings, actions.

Thread code

```
#include assert.h
#include pthread.h

void* PosixThreadMainRoutine(void* data)
{

    // I want to call here, example [Display click:self];
    // but i only see [Controller]... 
    int ac = 0;
    while (ac < 8)
    {
        sleep(1);
        printf("Test");
        ac++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
void LaunchThread()
{

    // Create the thread using POSIX routines.
    pthread_attr_t  attr;
    pthread_t       posixThreadID;
    int             returnVal;

    returnVal = pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    assert(!returnVal);
    returnVal = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    assert(!returnVal);

    int     threadError = pthread_create(&posixThreadID, &attr, &PosixThreadMainRoutine, NULL);

    returnVal = pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    assert(!returnVal);
    if (threadError != 0)
    {
        // Report an error.
    }
}

@end
```

Thread code works 100%, but i can't  call any variable or function in PosixThreadMainRoutine, can some one explain how to do it?
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute code in separated thread with accesing to @interface methods/variables its better to use:

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(Display:) toTarget:self withObject:t];`

or

`dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
  dispatch_apply(10, queue, ^(size_t i) {
    ///Thread code here
  });`

In your example unclear - what is [Display click:self]; As I see Display - its method but not interface. Also PosixThreadMainRoutine() are not instance or class method. That is why you cant invoke call method. In general you dont have access because compiler dont know interface with name Dispaly and dont know declaration of click: method.

I sugest you next article: [From C++ to Objective-C](http://chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf)

Comment: Im still facing same problem, the Display were as example, i want from thread execute [self Display:(id)sender]; ,  sorry i forgot to add  in controller.h line:  - (IBAction)Display:(id)sender;

Comment: try to pass self in last argument of pthread_create and then in PosixThreadMainRoutine(void* data) you can call method using [(Controller*)data Display: nil]. But its not "Cocoa style" of development.

Comment: Can't pass self, i'm getting  undeclarated identifier "self", and your line [(Controller*)data Display: nil] don't do anything. Could you explain where to insert, or modify  in pthread_create

Comment: It's imposible, to much syntax error and to much undetifier variables to handle, i know there is indirect call method, i can use [(Controller*)data Display: nil]; , but it's aren't executing, i tryied  SEL method = @selector(Display); [Controller performSelector:method];, but i get syntax error

Answer (score 0):

**Controller.m**

```
I deleted thread, and i used this example:
 [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(Display:) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 


- (IBAction)action:(id)sender{
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(Display:) toTarget:self withObject:nil]; 
}
```

It works like charm! i will save code , if someone knows answer i will try in currect situation.